# How to fetch some specific content with Bolt

Tags: bolt-cms

I use Bolt for powering our website and I was wondering how to fetch some specific content. In the documentation I found the following line:

```
{% setcontent myproducts = 'products' where { price: '!' } %}
```

Can I edit this in this:

```
{% setcontent recaps = 'recaps' where { recap: '1' } %}
```

When editing an entry I can set (checkbox) if there is a recap or not. Does the code above fetch only entries that have the recap checkbox checked?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that will fetch records where the checkbox is ticked.

Apart from the documentation, the cheatsheet here: http://cheatsheet.bolt.cm/#setcontent-tag

gives a quick overview of the types of query you can do with setcontent.